# Determining the position of the specific combination with repetition

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A $k$-combination with repetitions, or $k$-multicombination, or multisubset of size $k$ from a set $S$ is given by a sequence of $k$ not necessarily distinct elements of $S$ (size $n$), where order is not taken into account. Click [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) for details. However, there is one restriction that each element can't be more than $n$ times. The number of such combinations is given by (look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90419/combination-with-repetition-with-an-upper-bound) for the explanation):
$$\left(\!\!\!\binom{n}{k}\!\!\!\right)-\binom{n}{1}\left(\!\!\!\binom{n}{k-(n+1)}\!\!\!\right)+\binom{n}{2}\left(\!\!\!\binom{n}{k-2(n+1)}\!\!\!\right)-\ldots.$$
My question is following. How can I determining the position of some specific combination? This problem appears on my programming task where I want to save my computer memory.

**Example.** $n=6$, $k=9$, the number of the combinations with repetitions and no more than $n$ repetitions is
$$\left(\!\!\!\binom{6}{9}\!\!\!\right)-\binom{6}{1}\left(\!\!\!\binom{6}{2}\!\!\!\right)=1876.$$
My specific combination is $\lbrace 1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3\rbrace$. I want to add specific number between $1$ and $1876$ for my specific combination.

Comment: Do you mean the size of S to equal the maximum number of matching elements in the combination?  You used $n$ for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(n,k,m)$ be the number of $k$-multicombinations from an $n$-set, in which no element may appear more than $m$ times.

Suppose we write down, in order, a multicombination of $\{1,2,\ldots,7,8\}$, and add $n-1$ bookmarks for each increment in the digits: $$'1'1'1'1'1|2'2'2|3'3'3'3||5'5'5'5'5||7'7|8'8'8'$$

Give the name $a_i$ to the position (increasing from left to right) of the bookmark after the digit $i$.

Now you want to count the multicombinations which come *before* it in dictionary order. Suppose such a multicombination has bookmarks $a_1', a_2',\dots$ (The one shown above has $5,3,4,0,5,0,2$.) Then it belongs to one of the following categories:

- $a_1<a_1'$
- $a_1=a_1'$ but $a_2<a_2'$
- $a_1=a_1'$ and $a_2=a_2'$ but $a_3<a_3'$, etc.

These could be counted like this:

- $\sum_{i=a_1+1}^m f(n-1,k-i,m)$
- $\sum_{i=a_2+1}^m f(n-2,k-a_1-i,m)$
- $\sum_{i=a_3+1}^m f(n-3,k-a_1-a_2-i,m)$, etc.

a total of $n-1$ sums, any of which can be empty.

It may be possible to simplify the total by taking advantage of properties of $f$ with fixed $m$, for example, a recurrence relation.

**Edit.** Let's consider the case $m=3$.
$$\begin{array}{c|cccccccccccccccc}
_n\backslash^k&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15\\\hline
1&1&1&1&1\\
2&1&2&3&4&3&2&1\\
3&1&3&6&10&12&12&10&6&3&1\\
4&1&4&10&20&31&40&44&40&31&20&10&4&1\\
5&1&5&15&35&65&101&135&155&155&135&101&65&35&15&5&1\end{array}$$

Obviously if you've been working on this problem you've seen a table like this before. The recurrence is $$f(n,k,m)=\sum_{i=0}^mf(n-1,k-i,m)$$
You will easily find that $f(6,8,3)=546$. Now consider the multicombination $11233566$ with bookmarks $2,1,2,0,1$. How many entries come before it on a sorted list? Applying the method, we sum:

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccccccccccccc}
_n\backslash^k&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15\\\hline
1&\boxed{1}&\boxed{1}&1&1\\
2&\boxed{1}&\boxed{2}&\boxed{3}&4&3&2&1\\
3&1&3&\boxed{6}&10&12&12&10&6&3&1\\
4&1&4&10&\boxed{20}&\boxed{31}&40&44&40&31&20&10&4&1\\
5&1&5&15&35&65&\boxed{101}&135&155&155&135&101&65&35&15&5&1\end{array}$$

to get $1+1+1+2+3+6+20+31+101=166$. And if you ask your computer to sort the list of $546$ combinations, you will find that $11233566$ is indeed the $167$th item on the list.

Comment: I can't understand your answer. Can You give an example?

Comment: Say you have 111222333, and the limit for any symbol is five. The strings appearing before it in the list must be the completions of 1111..., 11111..., (moving the first bookmark to the right) then below them the completions of 1112222..., 11122222... (moving the second bookmark to the right).

Comment: Let $n=6$, $m=6$, $k=2$. Then the first sum can't exceed $1+5$, the second sum can't exceed $1+4$, ..., the fifth sum can't exceed $1+1$. From this it can be concluded that total sum can't exceed $20$. However, $f(6,2,6)=21$... I think that the answer is incomplete. Can you enumerate all combinations for this case with $k=2$?

Comment: The list will go 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 33, 34, 35, 36, 44, 45, 46, 55, 56, 66. There are twenty-one numbers, therefore we would expect that the maximum number of predecessors for any number is 20. Fix $m\ge k$ and then the number of predecessors for "34" must be $f(5,1)+f(5,0)$ (first sum) plus $f(4,1)+f(4,0)$ (second sum) plus $f(3,0)$ which makes $6+5+1=12$, and "34" is indeed 13th in the list.

Comment: I have edited my answer to give a fuller example using a table of results.